# Do bridges become useless after a certain amount of time?

Tags: bridge, censorship

After a specific amount of time, do bridges generated from https://bridges.torproject.org become useless in circumventing Tor censorship? Do these bridges eventually become recognized as Tor bridges? What if these bridges come with a pluggable transport such as Obfs4 or Meek?

Comment: china blocks tor bridges by obtaining full list of them.
obfs4 prevents active probing but don't prevent someone retrieving bridge descriptor

Comment: China doesn't have a list of Tor bridges. Instead, they fingerprint Tor traffic so bridges are usually detected.

Comment: "China" crawls several sources of bridges (mail, website) and makes a list out of the results. It uses it to block those bridges. However they also have other means to find out information about bridges, like @Swangie wrote.